# Maximize window and bring it in front with powershell

Tags: powershell, window

Is there a way to bring a window in front from powershell?
I tried this to hide all windows (working) and bring me the powershell back (not working)

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$shell.MinimizeAll()

$a = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "powershell"}
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($a.ID)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: works if I don't minimize windows using $shell.MinimizeAll()

Comment: @ravikanth It seems that you are right, if the windows is not minimized than the code is working. So perhaps I need to change my question title.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx) has a cmdlet to assist with this.   You use it like so:

```
Set-ForegroundWindow (Get-Process PowerShell).MainWindowHandle
```

or

```
Set-ForegroundWindow (Get-Process -id $pid).MainWindowHandle
```

To activate/show a window try this (assuming you're on PowerShell 2.0):

```
$sig = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
Stop-Process -Name Notepad -ea 0;Notepad.exe
$hwnd = @(Get-Process Notepad)[0].MainWindowHandle
# Minimize window
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 2)
# Restore window
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4)
Stop-Process -Name Notepad
```

Comment: It seems that it is not working with $shell.MinimizeAll()


`$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$shell.MinimizeAll()

Set-ForegroundWindow (Get-Process -id $pid).MainWindowHandle`

has no effect

Comment: Thanks Keith. ShowWindowAsync is the solution for my problem but I have to put a "sleep" between MinimizeAll() and ShowWindowAsync. It seems that MinimizeAll() is a asyc task and if it has a lot of windows to minimize ShowWindowAsync is called to fast.

Comment: I had issues with ShowWindowAsync, even though the window is maximized and suppossedly activated it may not be the top-most window. As such you may want to use SwitchToThisWindow afterwards.
The definition from PInvoke is:
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab)

Comment: According to the docs of the [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) function the value 4 means SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE, whereas the value 9 means SW_RESTORE, which is what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

This is cheating a bit since it's using WScript, but the following one-liner  places the window in the foreground without requiring any external cmdlet installation.

In the example below, "notepad" is the process name associated with the window.

Credit goes to the Idera forum posting [here](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/bringing-window-in-the-foreground) by JSanders:

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((get-process notepad).MainWindowTitle)
```

Comment: this just returns with "False" for me

Comment: If your window is minimized as a tray item it will not have a main window title.

Comment: @Scott Dudley - It doesn't do what you suggested for me

Answer (score 0):

Wscript one liner is working for me when I replace .MainWindowTitle to .Description at the end. So the line becomes:

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((get-process notepad).Description)
```

Yet to find a similar one liner for maximizing it...