# C# Close Excel Instance opened by another application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering if some other software create Excel instance, is it possible from c# to access that instance and close but without killing the process ?
I had tried with `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")` but that is throwing me the error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))'
```

Comment: Is it under a different user? If so are you executing with admin rights?

Comment: Started by someone else process you [have to kill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6046916/1997232) normally.

Comment: It is same user, there is no special rights.

Comment: @sinatr agree, but that is creating me a problem that time to time I must restart server, because excel start to failing. If I forgot to check the server, tomorrow maybe will not do the job...

Comment: You're not running this as a service, just a normal WinForms or console app? Are either of the two answers here useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664079/getactiveobject-command-fails-for-windows-8-and-windows-10?

Comment: Correct, it is not as a service it is WinForm.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work.
I had used

```
using Excel  = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
```

later in code I used:

```
var app = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

And this had created me a problem. I changed the code to:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
```

and

```
var obj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
obj.Quit();
```

And now this is working normally.

Comment: So in the first example you are NOT calling `.Quit()` in the second you are calling `.Quit()` and are surprised why the first example doesn't end the excel application?

Comment: For sure  later I had add `.Quit().` before I had exception on first line `var app = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); ` -> This line had create me exception from question above... P.S. I was not ask why application is not ending, I had ask how to access to already open instance of Excel generated by another system.