# Maximize window and bring it in front with powershell but with Internet Explorer

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I followed the following link ([Maximize window and bring it in front with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993926/maximize-window-and-bring-it-in-front-with-powershell)) instructions to make this happen but with internet explorer tab. Unfortunately it throws a few errors. Here is my code.

```
$sig = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool 
ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
Stop-Process -Name iexplore -ea 0;iexplore.exe
$hwnd = @(Get-Process iexplore)[0].MainWindowHandle
# Minimize window
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 2)
# Restore window
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4)
```

Throws the following errors:

```
    iexplore.exe : The term 'iexplore.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:35
+ Stop-Process -Name iexplore -ea 0;iexplore.exe
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (iexplore.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: `throws a few errors` **_what errors?_**

Comment: As evidenced *by your error messages*, you don't have an `iexplore` process running, so how do you expect to bring it to the front?

Comment: This is the error that pops up when I have a window launched

Comment: As an alternative to just `iexplore.exe` after the `Stop-Process` command, you can try using `Start-Process iexplore.exe`

Comment: This fix launches an internet explorer window, but it is not maximized

Comment: Have a look at the [WindowStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6#parameters) parameter of Start-Process