# How to maximize the apps has been minimize in Window?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How to maximize the apps has been minimize?
Because this apps somethime will suddently stop. I realize it only show the word Stop or Running in apps when maximize. When minimize it, after it move to background app, I cannot know whether it has been stop or running.

[image]

And this is the example when maximize the apps, it will show like this.

[image]

Comment: are you SURE that you require this for powershell version 2? that is very out of date ... and your images look like they are from win10. that version of windows comes with powershell version 5.1 ...

Comment: Ya, you are right. It is because I have few server...old one is powershell 2.0 and new server is powershell 5.0 and the screenshot I take from the new server. You mean the maximize function only can use in powershell 5.0?

Comment: nope ... i was asking if you really needed your code to work on ps2. you may want to add that specific detail to your Question.

Comment: you may want to look at this SO post ... >>> Maximize window and bring it in front with powershell - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993926/maximize-window-and-bring-it-in-front-with-powershell <<< it mentions a ps2 solution.

Comment: I need it can works in Poweshell 2.0 and powershell 5.0. Or do you know any way I can get detect the apps is running or stop other than this was after it being minimize?

Comment: Face this problem: The term 'Set-ForegroundWindow' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

Comment: the post mentions that you need to add a helper module. other than that, all i can do is refer you to `Get-Help Get-Process`.

Comment: Just try for it...Hmmm... this way is able bring the app to the front only when it is maximize. It can maximize it when hide in background

Comment: sorry ... i am out of ideas. [*blush*] hopefully, some kind person with better info will drop by & enlighten us both. [*grin*]