# Is there a way to Maximize the Windows app using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I think it is hard and couldn't find a solution for this one. I want to maximize the Windows app using PowerShell command line. For example, firefox or chrome.

Comment: Not it is not.  Yet, are you saying, start FF maximize, or maximize and current instance of FF. Though frowned upon, you can just use `SendKeys` to hit the app window and deal with your use case. There are older modules for this use case as well. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx. You can do this via user32.dll as well. All of the above have plenty of examples in blogs, articles, videos, and even posts right here on SO on this topic. SO, your question can be seen as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a potential duplicate of this SO Q&A.

[Maximize window and bring it in front with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993926/maximize-window-and-bring-it-in-front-with-powershell)