# Minimize Process from powershell/python using Process ID (PID)

Tags: python, powershell, ctypes, pywin32, win32gui

I'm writing a python script for an app lock. For this, I'm executing the `Get-Process -Name "notepad++"` PowerShell command using python subprocess to get the process id.
[image: Screenshoot of Process]

Now, using `psutil` I'm able to kill the process. But my objective is to **minimize the windows** in a while loop either using powershell/python. So, the program becomes unusable until the user enters the password.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791489/how-do-i-take-out-the-focus-or-minimize-a-window-with-python ? The answer would by the same for PowerShell (call native API function `ShowWindow`), but it'd probably require more code written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Powershell, you could do it with the use of the UIAutomationClient methods without having to rely on native calls.

Here is a small example to demonstrate how to check the window state and minimize the window if not.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName UIAutomationClient

$MyProcess = Get-Process -Name "notepad++"

$ae = [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::FromHandle($MyProcess.MainWindowHandle)
$wp = $ae.GetCurrentPattern([System.Windows.Automation.WindowPatternIdentifiers]::Pattern)


# Your loop to make sure the window stay minimized would be here
# While...
$IsMinimized = $wp.Current.WindowVisualState -eq 'Minimized'
if (! $IsMinimized) { $wp.SetWindowVisualState('Minimized') } 
# End While
```

**Reference**

[How to switch minimized application to normal state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70629441/934946)